# Facing Segmentation fault When reading video using ffmpeg, because the address of "pFormatCtx-> streams [i]-> codecpar" is 0x00

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

When reading real time video stream by using ffmpeg, `pFormatCtx-> streams [i]-> codecpar` is **0x00**, but `pFormatCtx-> streams [i]`is **0x55555579bbc0.**
my source code is as below where error occurs in line `if (pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)`

```
    //open media file
    if (avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, url, NULL, &avdic) != 0) {
        std::cout<<"can't open the file. \n";
        return;
    }

    //find the infomation of the stream
    if (avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx, NULL) < 0) {
        std::cout<<"Could't find stream infomation.\n";
        return;
    }

    //find the parameters of the video stream
    int videoStream = -1;
    cout<<pFormatCtx->nb_streams<<endl;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++) {
        if (pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            videoStream = i;
        }
    }
    if (videoStream == -1) {
        std::cout<<"Didn't find a video stream.\n"<<std::endl;
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to add a couple of null-pointer checks?

Comment: You need to open a codec, then copy the parameters from the codec to the format context.

Comment: By the way, you could use `av_find_best_stream()`.

Comment: after adding null-pointer checks, error also occurs

Comment: my program can run in my laptop while break in the server, both stream index is equal to 1, av_find_best_stream() seems not  to work here

Answer (score 0):

Soloving this problem by upgrading my server system to `Ubuntu 20.04`,for reasons that old system `18.04` can't make correct linke the ffmpeg dynamic libraries